# Фильтрация ListView или DataGrid по нескольким критериям?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, datagrid

Допустим есть контрол таблицы неважно какой, нужно как по фото реализовать фильтр или группировку. Как это можно сделать?

[image: Грид]

Comment: Вы разобрались как использовать тот совет, который вам дал @megafonishe или нужно написать пример?

Answer (score 0):

Элементы GUI сами по себе с данными не оперируют, тут нужны манипуляции с DataSource. У List, например, есть методы OrderBy и GroupBy.

Comment: У `List` нету методов `OrderBy` и `GroupBy`. Это методы расширения.

Comment: Думаю, тут будет уместно добавить пример ;)